# Firebase not retrieve last data when data changes and not execute conditions inside addValueEventListener in the right way

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to execute some code in my addValueEventListener based on conditions of values in database, but when data changes, listener execute conditions based on old data, and at the second try listener perform data which I want to use. however data change listener perform listenr(-1) data. To be more clear, if "disable" or "stop" child exist I don't want  to execute the code, but after data are updated and these children not existing, conditions when I call AddMessage method not executing again,  but it execute method when I call for the second time, it perform correctly till next update of the data where it start again same issue.

```
sendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AddMessage();
    }
});

private void AddMessage() {
    nListener = RootRef.child("List Ref").child(messageReceiverID).child(messageSenderID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild("disable") && !dataSnapshot.hasChild("stop")) {
                    HashMap <String,String> chatMessageMap = new HashMap <>();
                    chatMessageMap.put("from", messageSenderID);
                    chatMessageMap.put("type", "check");
                    chatMessageMap.put("content", messageText);
                    MessagesRef.child(messageReceiverID).push().setValue(chatMessageMap);
                    RootRef.child("List Ref").child(messageReceiverID).child(messageSenderID).removeEventListener(nListener);
                } else {
                    RootRef.child("List Ref").child(messageReceiverID).child(messageSenderID).removeEventListener(nListener);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: do you want to call function all time value change or just run when single value change ?

Comment: Are you saying that child nodes get deleted when you update the data using above code ?

Comment: @Ashish I call function when sending message with clickListener , but when data changes, functions execute conditions on last update not current data...

Comment: @Dharmaraj child node are not deleting but they are updated base on other user  prefferences or navigation, but while I'm sending a message and other user change this data my ValueListener is not retrive it in first execute but  I need to call a second to call it

Comment: Try changing it to `MessagesRef.child(messageReceiverID)..updateChildren(chatMessageMap);` once.

Comment: Please add the code how are you retrieving [calling] the data that isn't being called in first attempt .

Comment: @Dharmaraj problem is not when update data but in the conditions, I want to send a message to a specific user, but before I need to check if I'm allowed to send it. when I'm in the activity and user change his preferences so he decide to block me , I can still send him a message only once despite the fact the conditions is changed, when I try to send again conditions works fine and tell me the user has blocked You...

Comment: Okay I am clear to your question. Can you say me wherever are you storing the variable that user is blocked or not? I mean blocked status? Are you storing it in realtime-database? If yes, please post the picture of database structure. Also post the code which sends the message. The code posted by you seems irrelevant to your query. How do you send message? I need that code too

Comment: @Dharmaraj blocked and stop status are stored in realtime database, for those I'm calling addValueEventListener to handle if a user has blocekd me or not, then i execute setValue dependes on this result...(if he has blocked me it will be a child block with my id as value)

Comment: Please post whatever I have asked, I'll definitely help you. I need: (1) Database Structure screenshot where you store the STATUS. (2) The code which retrieved/Calls the status from database. Thank you. The main issue is I can't see any code which checks if the users is blocked directly. So I need to check it through your database.

Comment: @Dharmaraj 1-structure of firebase is updated with a link cause of my reputation, 2-the code which retrieve data from firebase is posted up, depends on this result i execute the setValue

Comment: Yeah, but where the the STATUS VARIABLE which stores if user is blocked or not?

Comment: Does, that stop means?? The value of stop, that UID is blocked by `gWd` UID guy?

Comment: if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild("disable") && !dataSnapshot.hasChild("stop")){ MessagesRef.child(messageReceiverID).push()
                                                    .setValue(chatMessageMap);  }

Comment: You can't just block him by checking if the STOP node exist .. .

Comment: and how will you block multiple users?? You need to modify the structure a bit.

Comment: Please check my answer. Because I'm lacking knowledge of your logic and don't have code of how those nodes are formed. So make sure you put those `<UID_OF_RECEIVER>` and `<UID_OF_SENDER>` values correctly.

Comment: Let me know if its working else I can try something else

Comment: Understand you..

Answer (score 0):

```
sendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        String stoppedUser;

        myDbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("List Ref").child(<UID_OF_RECEIVER_OF_MESSAGE>);
        myDbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            try {
                stoppedUser = dataSnapshot.child(<UID_OF_SENDER>).child("stop").getValue().toString();

                //Now use if-else statement
                if(<UID_OF_RECEIVER> == stoppedUser){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are blocked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    AddMessage();
                }

            }catch (Throwable e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
```

Though you can get `<UID_OF_SENDER>` by using `FirebaseUser currentUserUID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();` 
Make sure you put the value of `<UID_OF_RECEIVER>` correctly and also correct the database path if needed.

Comment: the problem is while I'm in the activity and node child(stop) changed value(that means other user block or unblock me) the code don't execute last update of node, but when I try for the second time he reads correctly till user decide to update it again...am I clear??

Comment: Your message handling system is complex. You need to update the status on all devices simultaneously

Comment: Same result as mine when other user update node child("stop") value.

Comment: I need more information on how your app works then  . . How are you updating the status?

Comment: my code is to long 1k lines in one activity and there are to many activities, but logic is simple: if a child exist do not execute the statement, like below if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild("disable") && !dataSnapshot.hasChild("stop")){ MessagesRef.child(messageReceiverID).push() .setValue(chatMessageMap); }.

Comment: It will be difficult then, can you push the code at github? If you are ok with it, not forcing though. But the issue is clear, status is being updated after user action.

Comment: I can't post at github atm, thnx for your time and help!

Comment: I found the solution after some days trying,same problem was in some other posts too, issue is do not retrieve data which can be changed inside onClickListener because they will not retrieve the last data updated, u must try a second click to retrieve the last data. If u keep reading data outside clickListener it should be good.

Comment: You should post the solution then. I don't think checking data before button click is good. It won't affect much but it will occupy some memory.